# CakePHP 3.x: How can I use Auth with a validation function other than validateDefault?

Tags: php, cakephp, authorization

I've been working with trying to get the [Auth component](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html) working in CakePHP 3.x, but all of the examples I'm seeing use the validationDefault function in the model in question.  Is there a way that I can configure it to use another validation function, say, validationCustom?

I'm seeing results for using different validation rules when saving an entity, but nothing in relation to Auth.

Comment: Authentication has nothing to with validation (as in using validators). You will have to be more specific as to what exactly you are referring to.

Comment: Then maybe I misunderstood the blog tutorial...